# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git when "bundle install"

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems, bundle, bundler

I have a directory that exists in a Gemfile.

When I execute `bundle install` in the directory, it shows this warning message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

but if I execute `git init` in the directory first, it does not show this warning message.

I know it's about the directory is it a git repository? But it doesn't make sense.

Why execute `bundle install` in the directory and need the directory to become a git repository first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug for Bundler in older version, which could be related: https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2039

Definitely not a problem with git or your git repo. Try updating bundler. latest stable version of bundler would fix this issue

Comment: but my bundler is the newest version 1.14.3, i run the app in docker container, i don't know does it effect?

Comment: I find the issue, because there is exist external include gem file that its gemspec file use the syntax `git ls-files`

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with that fatal warning. Finally I found that your comment of **bundle install** is correct.

> I find the issue, because there is exist external include gem file that its `gemspec` file use the syntax **git ls-files**

[image]

The syntax on my  gemspec file

```
spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").
select { |f| f.match(%r!^(assets|_layouts|_includes|_sass|LICENSE|README)!i) }
```

By uncomment `git ls-files` the warning is gone:

[image]